# Working of tree maps, time complexity at insert and read opertation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, maps

I want to know the tree map sorting functionality in Java. I know details about it, but does the sorting happen internally after every insert, that is O(nlogn) (kind or priority queue) or is it that while bulk insert the tree map dumps the data and starts sorting when we read/iterate through it?

Comment: The time complexity refers to the performance of an algorithm on an idealised machine so it doesn't change for different platforms. (The performance doesn't exactly follow the time complexity on real machines)

Answer (score 1):

A Java [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a "Red-Black tree based `NavigableMap` implementation", so insert and search take O(lg *n*) time per operation and iterating through it is O(*n*).

Answer (score 0):

The tree map is an implementation of a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) which is a type of binary search tree, so its keys are always sorted. The complexity for insert is O(logn), as there is no explicit sort. If you insert a bunch of elements, I would indeed expect that operation to be O(n*logn).